# Pared down version of RasPi

Tags: raspi-config

Is there a company that can build a pared down version of Raspberry Pi?

I only need a wifi transmitter/receiver and camera module to work with the Pi, which would hopefully reduce the size of the board.

Comment: If they could build it in a smaller size with just the WiFi + camera module + SOC, then it really wouldn't be a Raspberry Pi. You could take a board and solder off the components you don't want, but getting a Raspberry Pi smaller than the default one would make it not a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't believe that you can buy a paired down version of the raspberry pi. If you absolutely need a raspberry pi for the job, you could do what [this guy did](http://labs.domipheus.com/blog/pi-on-the-wall-wall-mounted-home-server-part-2-diet-pi/) on a model A raspberry pi. Basically, he removed everything he didn't need and ended up with a super thin raspberry pi.

You could also look at arduino or arduino clones which come in various sizes, they might be better suited for your size needs.